# Calculate row values dynamically based on previous row result

Tags: sql, sql-server, lag, row-number, unbound

I have table with project allocation for each users based on resource Id. We are creating some repot which needs to get the over allocation values by deducting the `Staffed` value from `Demand` value.

The demand value is unique based on combination of `Number`, `ResourceId` .

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Number      | ResourceId | Demand01 | Demand02 |  Staffed01 | Staffed02 | AssociateName | GroupName |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| RR-00000001 | 1019094    | 0.40     |  0.40    |  0.30      | 0.30      | Raja         |  RR/A      |
| RR-00000001 | 1019094    | 0.40     |  0.40    |  0.70      | 0.70      | Praveen      |  RR/A      |
| RR-00000001 | 1020688    | 0.00     |  0.00    |  0.12      | 1.00      | Bala         |  RR/A      |
| RR-00000002 | 1025136    | 0.00     |  0.00    |  0.00      | 0.00      | Naveen       |  RR/B      |
| RR-00000003 | 1020258    | 0.01     |  0.01    |  0.90      | 0.90      | Kumar        |  RR/C      |
| RR-00000002 | 1019096    | 0.01     |  0.01    |  0.30      | 0.30      | Arun         |  RR/D      |
| RR-00000002 | 1019096    | 0.01     |  0.01    |  0.70      | 0.70      | BBB          |  RR/E      |
| RR-00000002 | 1019096    | 0.01     |  0.01    |  0.30      | 0.30      | CCC          |  RR/E      |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**Expected Output:**

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Number      | ResourceId | Demand01 | Demand02 |  Staffed01 | Staffed02 |  OverStaffed01 | OverStaffed02 |  AssociateName  |  GroupName |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| RR-00000001 | 1019094    | 0.40     |  0.40    |  0.30      | 0.30      |     0.00       |     0.00      |    Raja         |  RR/A      |
| RR-00000001 | 1019094    | 0.40     |  0.40    |  0.70      | 0.70      |    -0.60       |    -0.60      |    Praveen      |  RR/A      |
| RR-00000001 | 1020688    | 0.00     |  0.00    |  0.12      | 1.00      |    -0.12       |    -1.00      |    Bala         |  RR/A      |
| RR-00000002 | 1025136    | 0.00     |  0.10    |  0.00      | 0.20      |     0.00       |    -0.20      |    Naveen       |  RR/B      |
| RR-00000003 | 1020258    | 0.01     |  0.01    |  0.90      | 0.90      |    -0.89       |    -0.89      |    Kumar        |  RR/C      |
| RR-00000002 | 1019096    | 0.01     |  0.01    |  0.30      | 0.30      |    -0.29       |    -0.29      |    Arun         |  RR/D      |
| RR-00000002 | 1019096    | 0.01     |  0.01    |  0.40      | 0.40      |    -0.40       |    -0.40      |    BBB          |  RR/E      |
| RR-00000002 | 1019096    | 0.01     |  0.01    |  0.30      | 0.30      |    -0.30       |    -0.30      |    CCC          |  RR/E      |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I have to derive `OverStaffed01 = Demand01 - Staffed01` but there is once constrain, if we have duplicate
`Number` and `ResourceId`, We have to adjust the demand values based on previous row.

For Example:

Combination of `Number:RR-00000002 and ResourceId:1019096` has three rows, so we can't directly calculate the value.

> For First row,(OverStaffed01 = Demand01 - Staffed01) 0.40 - 0.30 is
> greaten than 0 so which is not over staffed and we considered as 0.

> For Second row (OverStaffed01 = Demand01 - Staffed01) 0.10 - 0.70
> (Because we already reduced 0.30 from first row, so we have Demand01
> as 0.10) and OverStaffed01 is -0.60

Combination of `Number:RR-00000001 and ResourceId:1019094` has two rows, so we can't directly calculate the value.

> For First row,(OverStaffed01 = Demand01 - Staffed01) 0.01 - 0.30 is -0.29.

> For Second row (OverStaffed01 = Demand01 - Staffed01) 0.00 - 0.40
> (Because we already reduced 0.01 from first row, so we have Demand01
> as 0) and OverStaffed01 is -0.40

> For third row (OverStaffed01 = Demand01 - Staffed01) 0.00 - 0.30
> (Because we already reduced 0.01 from first row, so we have Demand01
> as 0) and OverStaffed01 is -0.30

For other rows , we have unique Number and ResourceId, so we can directly deduct and calculate `OverStaffed01`

**Query tried so far:**

```
CREATE TABLE table1
(
  Number varchar(100),
  ResourceId varchar(100),
  Demand01 decimal(18,2), 
  Demand02 decimal(18,2),  
  Staffed01 decimal(18,2), 
  Staffed02 decimal(18,2),
  AssociateName varchar(100), 
  GroupName varchar(100)
 )
 
 INSERT INTO table1 VALUES('RR-00000001','1019094', '0.40', '0.40', '0.30', '0.30', 'Raja', 'RR/A')
 INSERT INTO table1 VALUES('RR-00000001','1019094', '0.40', '0.40', '0.70', '0.70', 'Praveen', 'RR/A')
 INSERT INTO table1 VALUES('RR-00000001','1020688', '0.00', '0.00', '0.12', '1.00', 'Bala', 'RR/A')
 INSERT INTO table1 VALUES('RR-00000002','1025136', '0.00', '0.10', '0.00', '0.20', 'Naveen', 'RR/B')
 INSERT INTO table1 VALUES('RR-00000003','1020258', '0.01', '0.01', '0.90', '0.90', 'Kumar', 'RR/C')
 INSERT INTO table1 VALUES('RR-00000002','1019096', '0.01', '0.01', '0.30', '0.30', 'Arun', 'RR/D')
 INSERT INTO table1 VALUES('RR-00000002','1019096', '0.01', '0.01', '0.40', '0.40', 'BBB', 'RR/E')
 INSERT INTO table1 VALUES('RR-00000002','1019096', '0.01', '0.01', '0.30', '0.30', 'CCC', 'RR/E')


 SELECT Number, ResourceId, Demand01, Staffed01,  AssociateName, GroupName,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Number, ResourceId ORDER BY (Demand01 - Staffed01) DESC, (Demand02 - Staffed02) DESC) RN,
    Demand01- SUM (Staffed01) OVER (PARTITION BY Number, ResourceId ORDER BY (SELECT NULL) ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS OverStaffed01,
    Demand02- SUM (Staffed02) OVER (PARTITION BY Number, ResourceId ORDER BY (SELECT NULL) ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS OverStaffed02
FROM table1
```

**Update**

I have posted my recent updated query, which gives somehow correct result but still not expected result.

Comment: Is there proper definition for how the rows should be ordered? Because as it stands its random... but that won't be any good in the real world.

Comment: @DaleK Row order is actually random but we can order it by `ResourceId` for each specific combination of `Number` and `ResourceId`.

Comment: Yes, but your question specifically wants to deal with the case when those are duplicated, and to do anything like lag, you need an order that is defined and won't change. Else you won't get consistent results.

Comment: @DaleK Yes i understand that, We can order it by `ResourceId`

Comment: But thats duplicated, so the order is still undefined.

Comment: @DaleK `AssociateName` is unique for each combination of combination of `Number` and `ResourceId`.

Comment: Can there ever be more than 3 duplicate rows?

Comment: @DaleK It is dynamic and it can be any number but `AssociateName` is unique for that duplicate group.

Comment: By the way `ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING` is shorthand for `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW`, do not leave out the `ROWS` clause otherwise it defaults to `RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING` which is not the same thing

Answer (score 2):

Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
    Number varchar(100),
    ResourceId varchar(100),
    Demand01 decimal(18,2), 
    Demand02 decimal(18,2),  
    Staffed01 decimal(18,2), 
    Staffed02 decimal(18,2),
    AssociateName varchar(100), 
    GroupName varchar(100)
)
 
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES('RR-00000001','1019094', '0.40', '0.40', '0.30', '0.30', 'Raja', 'RR/A')
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES('RR-00000001','1019094', '0.40', '0.40', '0.70', '0.70', 'Praveen', 'RR/A')
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES('RR-00000001','1020688', '0.00', '0.00', '0.12', '1.00', 'Bala', 'RR/A')
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES('RR-00000002','1025136', '0.00', '0.10', '0.00', '0.20', 'Naveen', 'RR/B')
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES('RR-00000003','1020258', '0.01', '0.01', '0.90', '0.90', 'Kumar', 'RR/C')
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES('RR-00000002','1019096', '0.01', '0.01', '0.30', '0.30', 'Arun', 'RR/D')
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES('RR-00000002','1019096', '0.01', '0.01', '0.40', '0.40', 'BBB', 'RR/E')
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES('RR-00000002','1019096', '0.01', '0.01', '0.30', '0.30', 'CCC', 'RR/E')
```

Query:

```
with cte as (
    SELECT Number, ResourceId, Demand01, Demand02, Staffed01, Staffed02,  AssociateName, GroupName,RN,
        coalesce(sum(staffed01)over (partition by number,resourceid order by rn rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) ,0) PreviousStaffed01,
        coalesce(sum(staffed02)over (partition by number,resourceid order by rn rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) ,0) PreviousStaffed02    
    FROM
    (       
        SELECT Number, ResourceId, Demand01, Demand02, Staffed01, Staffed02,  AssociateName, GroupName,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Number, ResourceId ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) RN
        FROM table1
    ) X
)
select Number, ResourceId, Demand01, Demand02, Staffed01, Staffed02
    , (case when ((case when (demand01-previousstaffed01) <0 then 0 else (demand01-previousstaffed01)end) -staffed01)<0
    then ((case when (demand01-previousstaffed01) <0 then 0 else (demand01-previousstaffed01)end) -staffed01) else 0 end) OverStaffed01
    , (case when ((case when (demand02-previousstaffed02) <0 then 0 else (demand02-previousstaffed02)end) -staffed02)<0
    then ((case when (demand02-previousstaffed02) <0 then 0 else (demand02-previousstaffed02)end) -staffed02) else 0 end) OverStaffed02
    , AssociateName, GroupName 
from cte
```

Output:

| Number | ResourceId | Demand01 | Demand02 | Staffed01 | Staffed02 | OverStaffed01 | OverStaffed02 | AssociateName | GroupName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| RR-00000001 | 1019094 | 0.40 | 0.40 | 0.30 | 0.30 | 0.00 | 0.00 | Raja | RR/A |
| RR-00000001 | 1019094 | 0.40 | 0.40 | 0.70 | 0.70 | -0.60 | -0.60 | Praveen | RR/A |
| RR-00000001 | 1020688 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.12 | 1.00 | -0.12 | -1.00 | Bala | RR/A |
| RR-00000002 | 1019096 | 0.01 | 0.01 | 0.30 | 0.30 | -0.29 | -0.29 | Arun | RR/D |
| RR-00000002 | 1019096 | 0.01 | 0.01 | 0.40 | 0.40 | -0.40 | -0.40 | BBB | RR/E |
| RR-00000002 | 1019096 | 0.01 | 0.01 | 0.30 | 0.30 | -0.30 | -0.30 | CCC | RR/E |
| RR-00000002 | 1025136 | 0.00 | 0.10 | 0.00 | 0.20 | 0.00 | -0.10 | Naveen | RR/B |
| RR-00000003 | 1020258 | 0.01 | 0.01 | 0.90 | 0.90 | -0.89 | -0.89 | Kumar | RR/C |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5298d10b63a847d47a2fef4e91c9e1a8)*

Comment: Please only use quote text for real quotes or errors. Code and data should just be formatted as code and data.